# Why doesn't slam_gmapping sometimes update?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Why does slam_gmapping sometimes not update after a series of small movements (forward, backward, rotate left and rotate right)? Even if it is stationary for a long time, the map is not updated.

Example:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329091/why-doesn%27t-slam_gmapping-sometimes-update?/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, gmapping triggers the scan process after the robot has moved 1.0m away or rotated 0.5 radians since the last pose where the scan process was triggered.

Make sure that you move the robot far enough or set the [parameter](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping#Parameters) ~/temporalUpdate to something greater than 0:

```
~temporalUpdate (float, default: -1.0)
  Process a scan if the last scan processed is older than the update time in seconds. A value less than zero will turn time 
  based updates off.
```

Also, set the fixed frame in rviz to map instead of odom so that you get a correct visualization of your robot's state

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1